# value of a calculated index in smarty array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

Is there some way to calculate index inside the array brackets? I'll explain what i mean

I created an array in Smarty by exploding a string that i got from php. Now i want to get the value at the last index. So i tried this

```
{assign var='array' value=','|explode:$no}     //$no is the comma separated string
<h1>{$array[$array|@count]}</h1>               //this should be a blank value because i am going past the last index
```

this gave me error
`Fatal error: Smarty error: [in categories.tpl line 8]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $array[$array|@count]`

then i tried

```
{assign var='array' value=','|explode:$no}     //$no is the comma separated string
{assign var='c' value=$array|@count}
<h1>{$array[$c-1]}</h1>                        //$c is the count
```

this gave yhe following error
`Fatal error: Smarty error: [in categories.tpl line 8]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $array[$c-1]`

Finally the code which worked was this

```
{assign var='array' value=','|explode:$no}
{assign var='c' value=$array|@count}
{assign var='c1' value=$c-1}
<h1>{$array[$c1]}</h1>
```

Now this is stupid because i have to first calculate the index and store in it a variable to use it. Cant i use an "**on the fly generated index**"?
Thanks.

Comment: This smells of too much logic in your presentation. Can you move this into the PHP code?

Comment: @PaulDelRe maybe you are right but that can mean passing too much variables from php to smarty and my main motive is to know whether i can use "on the fly generated index"

Comment: Lovesh: Don't forget that Smarty is a templating language for presentation, not processing or logic.  This definitely sounds like a job for PHP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, I still first recommend doing the logic (or at least assign the array to the presentation layer instead of exploding a string) in your PHP or write a plugin or modifier.

From your code it seems that you'd like to get the last item in the string. I think you might be able to use PHP's [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) function.

```
{assign var='array' value=','|explode:$no}
<h1>{$array|@array_pop}</h1>
```